# Excludes posts that don't have attachments in the_content()

Tags: images, gallery, exclude

I'm trying to write a loop that excludes posts that don't have attachments in their content areas.

I've got 200 posts in a custom post type called "students". I need to do a query of all students with a gallery or attachment in their content area. NOT their featured image.

Can this be done? This is whats going on with my loop so far. Not working at all, I'm guessing that `$gotimages` isn't outputting posts with attachments...

---

**FINAL EDIT: The loop here works perfectly, the issue that I've found is that you can only assign images once. Which means, if you upload images to a post, then reuse the same images for another post, only the first post image will show. This loop works by association to the post.

Re-upload your images for every post to make this work and have unique images.**

**EDIT: Using the loop from s_ha_dum♦, this is getting closer to the thing I'm looking for, though it's only pulling one result in the loop.**

```
<?php
$args = array( 
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_status' => 'inherit',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_parent__not_in' => array(0),
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
      'value' => 'x',
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
  ),
  'fields' => 'post_parent'
);
$atts = new WP_Query($args);

$parents = array_unique(wp_list_pluck($atts->posts,'post_parent'));

//var_dump($parents);

// get your students posts
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'student',
    'post__in' => $parents
);
$students = new WP_Query($args);

// lets see some results
//var_dump($students->request);
//var_dump($students->posts);

echo '<hr />';

// Looping through the students
// I need to pull a random image from the post' gallery / attachements
// Unsure of how I do this
if ( $students->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $students->have_posts() ) {
        $students->the_post();

        echo get_the_title();
        echo '<hr />';
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
    echo 'No students exist';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

?>

Comment: Do not use `query_posts`. Rather use `WP_Query`. Rewrite your code and repost your new code.

Comment: @PieterGoosen updated to reflect an answer, that isn't correct, but is closer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please ***don't use `query_posts()`*** (emphasis mine)!

> > Note: ***This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes***. As
> >     explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
> >     the main query. `query_posts()` is ***overly simplistic*** and ***problematic*** way
> >     to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
> >     the query. It is ***inefficient*** (re-runs SQL queries) and ***will outright
> >     fail*** in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts
> >     pagination). ***Any modern WP code should use more reliable methods, like
> >     making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this purpose***.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Second, this isn't going to work:

```
$gotimages = get_children( array(
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_parent'    => get_the_ID()
)),

array(
  'key' => implode(', ', $gotimages),
  'compare' => '='
),
```

This line...

```
 'post_parent'    => get_the_ID()
```

... is probably going to be a problem as it will return the current post ID in the Loop, but your Loop doesn't start until later. Given how your code is written I think you are trying to construct a kind of sub-query, but it doesn't work like that.

This line ...

```
'key' => implode(', ', $gotimages),
```

... will definitely be a problem. `$gotimages`, if it has results, is going to be an array of objects. When you try to implode that you will get something like:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted
>   to string...

Try it with a post ID know to have attachments:

```
$gotimages = get_children( array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent'    => 1
));
var_dump(implode(', ', $gotimages));
```

And additionally, I am fairly sure that the `key` argument of a `meta_query` does not take a comma delimited string even if that object were to `implode()` correctly.

Third, `get_children()` is going to return all attachments, one of which is the featured image, but, additionally, WordPress handles attachments badly and once an image is attached to a post it is hard to unattach it. You will get images that where once displayed in the post body but are no longer displayed. So, logically, even if all of the code worked, what you are attempting won't work.

In fact, what you are trying to do is tricky and labor intensive as it is going to require a `regex` on the post body to search for images. If you have galleries involved it become more complicated still.

## So, how close can I get you?

> I need to do a query of all students with a gallery or attachment in
>   their content area. NOT their featured image.

This, if I've done it right, should get you close to "all students with a gallery or attachment in their content area":

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'post_status' => 'inherit',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_parent__not_in' => array(0),
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
      'value' => 'x',
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
  ),
  'fields' => 'post_parent'
);
$atts = new WP_Query($args);

$parents = array_unique(wp_list_pluck($atts->posts,'post_parent'));

// get your students posts
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'students',
  'post__in' => $parents
);
$students = new WP_Query($args);

// see some results
var_dump($students->request);
var_dump($students->posts);
```

What it doesn't do is:

- Compensate for cases where images where attached and then deleted
  from the post body. Those will still show up.
- And cases where images where manually written into the post body.
  Those will not show up.

Your other option would be to search your post type for some plausibly identifiable string:

```
$args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'students',
  's' => '<img '
);
$students = new WP_Query($args);
```

I am not sure how robust that will be but it does return some reasonable results when I try it.

Comment: Such an in-depth answer, I really appreciate this, however, the loop only shows 1 result. No matter how many posts there are.

Comment: Using `$students->the_post();` I can't only get one result back. I don't know if I'm missing something here

Comment: Updated the question to reflect your loop, hoping it helps find a solution

Comment: I thought through this pretty carefully. If you are not getting the results you expect I think the problem is with _what_ you are querying for and not with the query itself, but if you can identify what should be returned that isn't that would help.

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of all the students that have uploaded images to their content area. Then in this loop, show 1 random image from each student's post (the_content).

Comment: Ok. "1 random image from each student's post" is a very different thing than asked in the question, and it is a much trickier thing to boot.  You are going to need something like [these](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+UNION) and I don't have time to write that.

Comment: @s_ha-dum That part is quite difficult, and i'm working on it. But the first part of getting it to list just the names of the students isn't showing more than the first student. I appreciate you time spent on this already, and I thank you for that

Comment: My code pulls attachments first, then students. Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: well to make sure it's not being influenced by anything else, i've used it on a blank front-page.php